# Saving output to variable not working in Azure-CLI DevOps task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Trying to save an output of azure advisor recommendation on to a variable so that i can pass on to next task.

However no matter what syntax I try, and believe me i have tried all possible combinations, the variable doesn't get saved.
Interestingly, these work in cloud shell (bash)
for E.g.

```
rgName="$(az group list --query "[?tags.Test=='yes'].name" --output tsv)" 
az group show -n $rgName
```

This works just fine in cloud shell. But not in DevOps azurecli task.
I also referred to multiple examples given in stack overflow itself, but none of them work.
Using task version 1.*

```
rgName' is not recognised as an internal or external command,
```

Can someone give an working example for DevOps Task?

Note: BTW the whole reason for me using cli is because cant find Advisor RM module and the Az module wont load correctly in task version 4.*

Comment: Do you need save a variable to the next tasks? did you try `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=rgName']value"` ?

Comment: no, that is what i am looging for. I simply couldnt save the results to 'rgName=' in the command 
rgName="$(az group list --query "[?tags.Test=='yes'].name" --output tsv)"

Answer (score 0):

As Shayki mentioned above, `task.setvariable` can help with setting a variable from a script. The same has been detailed in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cshell#set-in-script) document. In a nutshell, you would have to do this:

```
rgName=$(az group list --query "[?tags.Test=='yes'].name" -o tsv | tr '\n' ' ')
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RESULT]$rgName"
```

The `task.setvariable` is a logging command and does not update the environment variables, but it does make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same job. Notice that the results are separated by CRLF and not spaces, and hence the trimming `tr '\n' ' '`. Now, in the subsequent tasks where you need the variable, you may use it in this way:

```
echo "Result: $(RESULT)"
```

Refer to [this](https://lurumad.github.io/set-output-variables-in-azuredevops-pipelines-tasks) blog to get a detailed walkthrough. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of task.setvariable.My issue was with getting the results of the command into 'rgName' variable.
Common sense says that rgName='whatever command' would save the results into 'rgName' but for some reason it wasnt working in this task.
If the first step itself doesnt work, then i cant use 
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RESULT]$rgName"
because, based on what i was facing $rgName would always be null as the results arent getting saved there.

Comment: Are you still blocked on this?

Comment: I have moved past the issue using other means, however the issue still EXISTS when i tested today. no matter what syntax i try, i cant get this to work inside the CLI task. same syntax works in cloushell though.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was to use a Linux agent job and not a Windows agent then add the Azure CLI task to run on the Linux agent, specifically the ubuntu-16.04.